# ConfigurationProperties does not take effect due to lack of ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor

Tags: java, spring-boot, configurationproperties

In my Spring Boot project, I have used Maven multi-module to organize the project structure. I have placed the database configuration in the `common-db` module and designed a `DataBaseProperties` class to add new functionality to the default database configuration in Spring Boot.

```java
@Configuration  
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")  
@Getter  
@Setter  
@ToString  
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)  
@Slf4j  
public class DataBaseProperties implements InitializingBean {  
  
    String driverClassName = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";  
  
    Integer initialSize;  
    Integer maxActive;  
    Integer minIdle;  
    Integer maxWait;  
  
    Boolean showSql = false;  
    String basePackage = "com.example.**.mapper";  
    String[] mapperLocations;  
    Boolean cacheEnabled = true;  
  
    @Override  
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {  
        log.info("configuration properties: {}", this);  
    }  
}
```

In the `common-db` module, I use `spring.factories` to inject the Bean:

```
# Auto Configure  
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=com.example.common.db.config.properties.DataBaseProperties
```

Then I import this `common-db` module into the main project. However, I found that `DataBaseProperties` cannot retrieve the configuration information.

I tried modifying the configuration prefix to `example.datasource`, but it didn't work. I also tried using `@EnableConfigurationProperties` to inject `ConfigurationProperties`, but the problem remained unresolved, and I'm not sure if it's due to incorrect usage or other reasons.

I also attempted to add the following Maven dependency, but it had no effect.

```xml
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>  
</dependency>
```

After debugging, I found that during the initialization of `DataBaseProperties`, the `BeanFactory` is missing `ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor`, which prevents it from obtaining the configuration information. However, I have written other `@ConfigurationProperties` classes that can retrieve the configuration information and have `ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor` during initialization.

By observing the `List<BeanPostProcessor> beanPostProcessors` field in `AbstractBeanFactory`, I found that `DataBaseProperties` is using `AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext`, while other `ConfigurationProperties` classes that can retrieve the configuration information use `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`. There may be other `ApplicationContext` being used, but what I can confirm is that `AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext` lacks `ConfigurationProperties`.

Now, I'm not sure why this PostProcessor is missing. Maybe it has always been missing? I hope someone can help me make the `ConfigurationProperties` class in my `common-db` module retrieve the configuration. I appreciate any help and thank you for reading this.